# Extract dyRangeSelector values from dygraph in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I've been using the dygraphs library to put some very nice timeseries plots in a shiny app. I particularly like using the `group` argument to `dygraph` in combination with `dyRangeSelector` to sync the zoom level across multiple dygraphs.

Is there a way to make *other* shiny outputs reactive to user manipulations of the range selector? Take this example app which shows a simple dygraph and sums the series in a table below:

```
# app.R
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(dplyr)

indoConc <- Indometh[Indometh$Subject == 1, c("time", "conc")]

ui <- fluidPage(
  dygraphOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderDygraph({
    indoConc %>%
      dygraph %>%
      dyRangeSelector
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    indoConc %>%
      filter(time >= min(indoConc$time), time <= max(indoConc$time)) %>%
      summarise(total_conc = sum(conc))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'd like that table to only sum over the time interval currently selected by the user. This means changing the `filter` line to use something other than those min/max points (which result in no filtration).

How can I extract those two values from the range selector in the appropriate format so I can use them in that `filter` call, and have the table update reactively as the user moves the sliders?

Comment: I can see theres some hidden inputs like `plot_date_window` I can use, thanks to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955578/r-shiny-dygraphs-series-reacting-to-date-window. The trick now is extracting my non-timeseries y values from that; is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `time` variable in the `dataframe` is a 3 digit variable I would suggest that you convert the `datetime` object into a `character` and then select the last 3 digits that you need, and coarse it to a `numeric` for further use, like so:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

indoConc <- Indometh[Indometh$Subject == 1, c("time", "conc")]
takeLastnvalues <- -3
ui <- fluidPage(dygraphOutput("plot"),tableOutput("table"))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()  
  observeEvent(input$plot_date_window,{
    value1 <- input$plot_date_window[[1]]
    value2 <- input$plot_date_window[[2]]
    value1 <- sub("Z", "", value1)
    value2 <- sub("Z", "", value2)
    value1 <- str_sub(value1,takeLastnvalues,-1)
    value2 <- str_sub(value2,takeLastnvalues,-1)
    values$v1 <- as.numeric(value1)
    values$v2 <- as.numeric(value2)
  })

  output$plot <- renderDygraph({
    indoConc %>%
      dygraph %>%
      dyRangeSelector
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    indoConc %>%
      filter(time >= min(values$v1), time <= max(values$v2)) %>%
      summarise(total_conc = sum(conc))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you are only able to extract integers. (in your screenshot `values$v1 = 2` and `values$v2 = 4`)

Comment: @GyD I noticed that too; is that an inherent limitation given my setup, or is there a way to get the "full" value of these endpoints?

Comment: I was working on the fix, but its to do with `dygraphs`itself where the timestamp is only up to the millisecond range and there are some tickets related to that already. You can howerver modify your `time`variable to be in thousands and then modify it back upon selection

Comment: @PorkChop ah I see, that's what I was worried might be the case, but at least there's a workaround. Would you mind linking those upstream tickets here for reference?

Comment: Some tickets are here [654](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/654), [46](https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/issues/46), [118](https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/pull/118). He explicitly converts the datetime object with max of 3 digits to milliseconds